# Fix child multiplication from its parrent BOM excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data from my customer a wrong BOM and cannot be fixed for moment, received in Excel - with a lot of records there. There is a simple way to fix the BOM? May some logic help I need, I have some VBA knowledge. Seems that the parents are written ok but the child's are no multiplied by its parent qty. At the second level the parent is affect by previous multiplication. On the column (corrected) is corrected values, manually made.
I can have multiple levels start from 0 until 20
How could be corrected the qty column in Excel to became like (corrected) column?

At row 59 parent is qty = 1 child's qty are ok. The issues starts at line 80 where parent is qty = 3 but child's qty will not follow (multiplied by parent). So when parent qty != 1 child's items have to be multiplied.
How this can be fixed from top to bottom of the list?

```
Level/levStr/partname       qty (corected)
1    +.1    802011          3
2    +..2   802010          1   3
2    +..2   FTH-15-01       6   18
2    +..2   PLT1M           6   18
2    +..2   604189          4   12
3    +...3  604032          1   12
3    +...3  6001-2RSL       2   24
3    +...3  604034          1   12
3    +...3  604161          1   12
3    +...3  6885-A-44-20    2   24
3    +...3  W151FL-M6-12    1   12
```

[image]

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I have formulated the question. I hope is clear now.

Comment: how is that data actually represented in a spreadsheet? Can you edit your question and post a screenshot?

Comment: The data is exactly as in example without the "corrected" column. The idea is to recalculate the qty column to be the same as the "corrected" column. I have put the  "corrected" column for reference, how should be. This table have been exported into excel from some application but is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my quick code in VBA. Its an ugly code but working.

```
Option Explicit
Dim mbResult As Integer

Dim CWS As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim clevel As Long
Dim cQuantity As Long
Dim cQuantityFix As Long
Dim ended As Boolean

Public Sub MainRun()

mbResult = MsgBox("Do you want to fix QTY BOM?", vbYesNo)
Select Case mbResult

Case vbYes

Case vbNo
    Exit Sub
Case vbCancel
    Exit Sub
End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

Sheets(1).Activate
Set CWS = ActiveSheet

lastRow = CWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
lastCol = CWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


clevel = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Level", CWS.Rows(1), 0)
cQuantity = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Quantity", CWS.Rows(1), 0)
cQuantityFix = CWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
'cQuantityFix = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Fix", CWS.Rows(1), 0)

Dim parentqty As Long

Dim r As Integer
Dim oLevel As Integer
oLevel = 0
ended = False

    For r = 2 To lastRow
        If ended = False Then
            Dim currlevel As Long
            Dim nextLevel As Long
            Dim qty As Long

            currlevel = Cells(r, clevel).Value
            nextLevel = Cells(r + 1, clevel).Value
            Cells(r, cQuantityFix).Select

            If IsEmpty(Cells(r, cQuantity)) Then
                    qty = 1
                    Cells(r, cQuantityFix).Value = qty
            Else
                    qty = Cells(r, cQuantity).Value
            End If

            If nextLevel > currlevel Then
                r = iCall(r, qty, nextLevel)
            End If
                Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox ("Job Done. Qty fix on the last column")
End Sub

Private Function iCall(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal multiplier As Integer, ByVal level As Integer) As Integer


Dim actRow As Long
Dim nextLevel As Long
Dim cQty As Long


    For actRow = row + 1 To lastRow
        If ended = False Then

            Cells(actRow, cQuantityFix).Select
                nextLevel = Cells(actRow + 1, clevel).Value
            If level = nextLevel Then
                cQty = Cells(actRow, cQuantity).Value * multiplier
                Cells(actRow, cQuantityFix).Value = cQty
            Else

                Dim oVal As Integer

                    oVal = Cells(actRow, cQuantity).Value
                    cQty = oVal * multiplier
                    Cells(actRow, cQuantityFix).Value = cQty

                If level < nextLevel Then

                    nextLevel = Cells(actRow + 1, clevel).Value
                    If nextLevel > 0 Then

                        If nextLevel > level Then
                            actRow = iCall(actRow, cQty, nextLevel)
                        Else
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    Else
                        ended = True
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                Else
                    If nextLevel > 0 Then
                        actRow = iCall(actRow, getParentLevelMultiplier(actRow, nextLevel), nextLevel)
                        iCall = actRow
                        Exit Function
                    Else
                    ended = True
                     Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next actRow
End Function

Private Function getParentLevelMultiplier(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal level As Integer) As Integer

Dim crrlevel As Long
Dim i As Long

    For i = row To 1 Step -1
        Cells(i, clevel).Select
        crrlevel = Cells(i, clevel).Value
        If Cells(i, clevel) = level - 1 Then
            getParentLevelMultiplier = Cells(i, cQuantityFix)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```